# How can we get our data back from only GMM parameters?

Tags: python, probability, gmm

(Sorry if a similar question had raised before)..

if I fitted my data with Gaussian Mixture Model and got three parameters (Means, Covariances, Weights) with, for example, this python code:

```
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=8, covariance_type="full", max_iter=100, verbose=1).fit(x)
```

How can I get my original data **x** back by using only these three GMM parameters:
**gmm.means_**, **gmm.covariances_**, **gmm.weights_** with 8 components.

I need to reconstruct my data again. Thank you in advance!